# Unnamed unix domain socket has wrong address length

Tags: c, linux

When reading the address of a sending unix datagram domain socket in this minimal example program, I am getting an address length of 0, but the man page for unix domain sockets specifies that:

> unnamed: A stream socket that has not been bound to a pathname using
>             bind(2) has no name.  Likewise, the two sockets created  by  socket‐
>             pair(2)  are  unnamed.   When  the  address  of an unnamed socket is
>             returned, its length is sizeof(sa_family_t), and sun_path should not
>             be inspected.

I was expecting the address length of an unnamed socket to be 2 based on this man page. Am I misinterpreting the man page, does the man page not apply to unix sockets of type `SOCK_DGRAM` or am I simply reading the length incorrectly?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/un.h>

const char SOCK_NAME[] = { 0, 't', 'e', 's', 't' };
// or for pathnamed socket
// const char SOCK_NAME[] = "/tmp/test.uds";

const char PAYLOAD[] = "Hello!";

int main() {
    int rx_sock = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);

    if (rx_sock < 0) {
        perror("Create RX");
        exit(1);
    }

    int tx_sock = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);

    if (tx_sock < 0) {
        perror("Create TX");
        exit(1);
    }

    struct sockaddr_un bind_addr;
    bind_addr.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
    memcpy(bind_addr.sun_path, SOCK_NAME, sizeof(SOCK_NAME));

    socklen_t bind_len = sizeof(sa_family_t) + sizeof(SOCK_NAME);

    if (bind(rx_sock, (const struct sockaddr *)&bind_addr, bind_len) != 0) {
        perror("Bind RX");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (sendto(tx_sock, PAYLOAD, sizeof(PAYLOAD), 0, (const struct sockaddr *)&bind_addr, bind_len) < 0) {
        perror("Sendto");
        exit(1);
    }

    // For pathnamed socket
    // unlink(SOCK_NAME);

    struct sockaddr_un recv_addr;
    socklen_t recv_len = sizeof(recv_addr);
    char buffer[1024];

    ssize_t rx_count = recvfrom(rx_sock, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&recv_addr, &recv_len);

    if (rx_count < 0) {
        perror("Recvfrom");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("Address size of TX on receiver side: %d\n", recv_len); // 0

    recv_len = sizeof(recv_addr);

    if (getsockname(tx_sock, (struct sockaddr *)&recv_addr, &recv_len) != 0) {
        perror("getsockname");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("Address size of TX on sender side: %d\n", recv_len); // 2
}
```

Comment: Minor issue: `sizeof(PAYLOAD)` should probably be `strlen(PAYLOAD)`. You're getting the size of the pointer there. Otherwise, great question. Seems like a kernel bug. If the behavior is as intended then the man page needs an update. If you made the `SOCK_NAME` a real path like `/tmp/socktest`, and added an `unlink` before the `bind`, you'd have something portable to other Unices that don't have the "abstract namespace". It would be interesting to see if they do the same thing.

Comment: What's unclear about `has no name` and `sun_path should not be inspected`?  Why are you trying to write to it?

Comment: @stark I am writing to the path to bind the receiving socket to an abstract address

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley Thanks for pointing that out, I made `PAYLOAD` an array in the code to use the correct size. I also tried using a pathnamed socket and the address also has length 0 on the receiving side

Comment: @MaxBenson: The **sending** socket is unnamed. The receiver already knows the address they're bound to. `recvfrom()` returns the sender address, and because it is unnamed, there is no sender address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an <s>unnamed</s> unbound Unix domain datagram socket `tx_sock`, and an Unix domain datagram socket `rx_sock` bound to an abstract address in `bind_path`.

Note: According to [`man 7 unix`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/unix.7.html), unbound Unix domain *stream* sockets are *unnamed* in Linux, and their address lengths will be `sizeof (sa_family_t)`. According to POSIX.1, [unbound socket addresses are unspecified](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getsockname.html), so we really need to be careful about what we expect of unbound socket addresses and their lengths. In this particular case, in Linux, using the man page as a guide, an unbound Unix domain *datagram* socket has no address, so its length is zero.  (It even makes sense: zero address length indicates you cannot reply to the sender. With an unbound stream socket, there is a connection back to the sender, but no other way to reply to the sender but the connection itself; that is why in that case the address length is then nonzero, `sizeof (sa_family_t)`.)

Abstract Unix domain socket addresses are a Linux extension; they begin with a NUL byte (`\0`), and are not visible in the filesystem.

You use `sendto(tx_sock, msg, msg_len, 0, bind_path, bind_path_len)` to send a message.

You use `recvfrom(rx_sock, buffer, sizeof buffer, 0, &recv_addr, &recv_addrlen)` to receive the message (with `recv_addrlen` properly initialized to `sizeof recv_addr`).

Because `tx_sock` is not bound to any address, it is <s>unnamed</s> unbound: it has no address, cannot be replied to, and therefore `recv_addrlen == 0`.

If you add code to bind `tx_sock` to some other abstract address, you'll receive that address in `recv_addr` and `recv_addrlen`.

(I verified this behaviour with a test program using four threads, where each thread sends a message to each other thread, and prints all received messages and where they are from, with both standard addresses and abstract addresses. Everything works as documented.)

Comment: The man page states that an unbound and thus unnamed socket has an address length of 2 not 0. I added a call to `getsockname()` above, which confirms that reading the address of the TX socket on the TX side returns length 2, which is expected as per the man page, but reading the address of the TX socket on the RX side returns 0. So why does it return 0?

Comment: @MaxBenson: Ah, now I see the reason for the confusion. I edited my answer to make it hopefully clearer. You see, the term *"unnamed socket"* term only applies to stream sockets, not datagram sockets. To make my answer clearer, I used the term *"unbound"* to indicate a non-connected, non-bound socket. Simply put: *"bound"* -> full address, can respond; *"unnamed"* -> empty address, but can still respond (because a connected stream); and *"unbound"* -> no address, cannot respond.

Comment: I guess your explanation does add up, but I find the man page on this subject confusing. If the behaviour of returning 0 instead of 2 for datagram protocol really is standartized then the man page should mention this fact.

Comment: @MaxBenson: It only applies to Linux (POSIX.1 leaves it undefined!), but definitely the man page could/should describe the behaviour better. There are [easy mechanisms](https://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/reporting_bugs.html) for reporting these, but the hard part is getting the wording right. Knowing Kerrisks work, I am sure a clear additional paragraph to describe this [in patch form](https://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/patches.html) would be appreciated and included quite quickly. I'm not sure *my* English-fu is up to that task, though.

Answer (score -2):

Of course you're getting a name length of zero.

The first value in your `char` array is `0`, immediately terminating the string to a length of zero bytes:

```
const char SOCK_NAME[] = { 0, 't', 'e', 's', 't' };
```

> unnamed: A stream socket that has not been bound to a pathname using bind(2) has no name.

does not apply, because you **are** using `bind()` to bind the socket:

Comment: I am clearly not calling `bind()` on the unnamed transmitting socket

Comment: @AndrewHenle: It is the receiving socket that is bound; the sending socket is not. I got initially tripped by this, too.